Isekai manga where the guy gets a skill that makes women fall in love with him
At the start he’s talking to a goddess and she gives him a skill that will make him invincible (all women being in love with him and want to protect him) and reincarnates him.
It turns out she mixed up the world he was supposed to go to with a different much more violent one. the people who summon him are surprised by how weak he is and then the demon lord (who is female) appears and kills everyone but him because of the skill. I can’t remember much more of what happens.

i think the skill was "to be loved by the native population" , in this case it means the demons were the native population. each (female) demon general that comes in contact with the mc falls deeply in love with him. mc manages to "rescue" the princess but the demons cut her ankle tendons. then the mc talks to a demon who is actually a human in disguise who trains him a little bit before leaving.

Zangyaku Sugiru Isekai demo Suzuki wa Kawaii

Takashi Suzuki is a young man who dreams of a heartwarming slow life in some other world. When he finally gets reincarnated into a different world, he receives the "unconditional love from all local species" cheat ability, thinking it will allow him to raise cute animals... But the world ends up being a horrible "anything-goes" apocalyptic wasteland reeking of blood, filled with executions, torture, looting, and ruled by the most cruel and brutal demons imaginable?! His only weapon is ultimate, unrivaled cuteness... So he decides to use that to butter the demons up and transform this blood and violence-filled world!

